# How to break a component content with multiple element inside it

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my Angular 13 project, there is a component sentenceContainer to show something like a sentence.
The sentence has words that each word also could be a sentence that has words that could be sentence and so on.
each word could be one of the 3 component I defined. let name them AComponent, BComponent or CComponent.
My problem is that I want to break the sentence when it's width reaches to the end of the sentenceContainer, but its not as simple as breaking a text, because there are many component nested to make a sentence.

This is an example of a sentence:

a(a b c(a a b b c) c) b b(b b b c c c a) c(c a) a(a b(a b a a a a c c c c)

a's are type of AComponent, b's are type of BComponent and c's are type of CComponent.

One solution is to cast the sentence to a simple text so breaking a simple string is easy. I don't want to cast the sentence to a text, because each word some specific feature like showing metadata as a popover while hovering.
I set overflow-x and some styles to the sentenceContainer but it didn't help.

Comment: How did you define a sentence ?

Comment: Words are stored in database, user select words from list to make a sentence, then I have to make the sentence.
Each word could have sentence or not be a sentence and be just a word, and I show word recursively until I get to then end, and end is a word that is not a sentence.

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear. You wrote that you "don't want to cast the sentence to a text", so what type/class is a sentence ?

Comment: One solution is to cast the sentence to a simple text so breaking a simple string is easy. I wrote this, because I couldn't convert the sentence to a simple string and I have to solve the problem with this constraints.

Comment: Please include the version of Angular that you are using. If your angular version is 2.0 or greater, then you should remove the angularjs tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by style all elements in all components to `white-space: pre-line`.